# A criterion for having Fredholm index 0

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

In reading a paper, I ran into the following Lemma:

> Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator from a Hilbert space, $H$, into $H$. Let $T$ have a kernel of dimension $d<\infty$. Assume $T$ has closed range and that $T^*-T$ is a compact operator. Then the range of $T$ has codimension $d$ also.

The authors omit the proof since it is "simple", but I got no idea after several hours of thinking. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need:

1. $T $ is semi-Fredholm, hence $T^*$ is semi-Fredholm ,
2. $ ind (T^*)=-ind(T)$,
3. If $K $ is compact,  then $T+K $ is semi-Fredholm and $ind (T+K)=ind (T) $

Now let $K=T^*-T $.

Then $T^*=T+K$, hence

$-ind(T)=ind(T^*)=ind(T+K)=ind(T)$.

Therefore $ind(T)=0$, which gives $codim(T(X))=d$.

Comment: How do you know that $T$ is Fredholm---in particular, why does its range have a finite codimension?

Comment: Pardon ! I mean semi- Fredholm ! I completed my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had the same question as @gerw after I saw the original answer....